# React Native nested navigation to achieve a landing screen with tabs (bottomTabNavigator) after Sign-In/Sign-Up(StackNavigator)

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-native-navigation

Here is an Expo Snack of my project : https://snack.expo.io/Sk3W8egTl

I have a StackNavigator to implement a simple Sign Up and Login functionality. It follows the structure provided in this article[link](https://heartbeat.fritz.ai/how-authentication-flow-works-in-react-native-apps-using-react-navigation-4-x-a30bb4d9e5d6)

I also want to have a screen that uses a bottom Tab navigator with just two tabs for a Home Screen and a Settings Screen that I can land on after the login.

My **App.js** looks like this :

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { Platform, StatusBar, StyleSheet, View } from 'react-native';

import {createAppContainer} from 'react-navigation';
import { createBottomTabNavigator } from 'react-navigation-tabs';
import AppContainer from './navigation'

import Home from "./screens/HomeScreen";
import Settings from "./screens/SettingsScreen";

const BottomTabNavigator = createBottomTabNavigator({ //for the bottom two tabs after landing from the login screen
  Home: {screen: Home},
  Settings: {screen: Settings},

});

//const App = createAppContainer(BottomTabNavigator); 

//export default App;

export default function App() {
  return <AppContainer />
}
```

The navigation folder has three files, namely :

**AppNavigation** - for the main screens in the app

```
import { createStackNavigator } from 'react-navigation-stack'
import Home from '../screens/HomeScreen'

const AppNavigation = createStackNavigator(
  {
    Home: { screen: Home }
  },
  {
    initialRouteName: 'Home'
  }
)

export default AppNavigation
```

**AuthNavigation** - for the login and sign up screens

```
import { createStackNavigator } from 'react-navigation-stack'
import Login from '../screens/Login'
import SignUp from '../screens/SignUp'

const AuthNavigation = createStackNavigator(
  {
    Login: { screen: Login },
    SignUp: { screen: SignUp }
  },
  {
    initialRouteName: 'Login',
    headerMode: 'none',
  }
)

export default AuthNavigation
```

**index.js** - to integrate them

```
import { createSwitchNavigator, createAppContainer } from 'react-navigation'
import AuthNavigation from './AuthNavigation'
import AppNavigation from './AppNavigation'


const SwitchNavigator = createSwitchNavigator(
  {
    Auth: AuthNavigation,
    App: AppNavigation
  },
  {
    initialRouteName: 'Auth'
  }
)
const AppContainer = createAppContainer(SwitchNavigator)

export default AppContainer
```

Right now I have the sign-in/sign-up pages and the bottom tabs separate but I want to be able to see the landing page with the two tabs after I sign in. I am really new to React Native and don't have an idea as to how to go about nesting the Navigators to achieve what I need. Please help me out here. Thank you!

Comment: You snack project is different than code you posted here

Comment: yes, please share a woring example so that we can help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's simple what you are trying to achieve. In place of createStackNavigator... of your AppNavigation put your

```
    createBottomTabNavigator({ //for the bottom two tabs after landing from the login screen
  Home: {screen: Home},
  Settings: {screen: Settings},

});
```

Comment: Thank you @kenodek that helped me greatly!